# How to bind only 'some' list items to the ListView in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a model dfined like this:

```
class MyImage
{
   public string imagePath {get; set;}
   public bool isIncluded {get; set;}
}
```

and the list to hold these models:

```
public List<MyImage> myImages {get; set;}
```

Now, I know how to bind this entire list to the `ListView`, but what I want is to have `ListView` displaying only the images of those models in which the property 'isIncluded' is set to true.

My current solution is to have another `List<MyImages>` in which I copy only those that are included, but I was wondering if there is any better solution.

Comment: You are looking for a [`ListCollectionView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.listcollectionview?view=netframework-4.7) and Filters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply hide the items to be excluded in the `ListView` in the view by defining an `ItemContainerStyle` with a `DataTrigger`:

```
<ListView ...>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding isIncluded}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a CollectionView and apply a filter...very simple

```
public ICollectionView SupportedDevices
    {
        get
        {
            if (Data != null)
            {
                return CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Data);
            }
            else
                return null;
        }
    }

    private string _searchedText = string.Empty;
    public string SearchedText
    {
        get { return _searchedText; }
        set
        {
            _searchedText = value;

            SupportedDevices.Filter = delegate(object obj)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_searchedText))
                    return true;

                DeviceInfo data = obj as DeviceInfo;
                if (data == null)
                    return false;

                return (
                    (data.Manufacturer.IndexOf(_searchedText, 0, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) > -1) ||
                    data.Model.IndexOf(_searchedText, 0, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) > -1
                    );
            };
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can avoid having another list. A more elegant solution might be a LINQ query on the property:

`public List<MyImage> MyImages => myImages.Where(i => i.IsIncluded).ToList();`

Another more intricate approach might be a [CollectionViewSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource(v=vs.110).aspx).